# UBER widget for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uber-api

I am developing an iOS app and am trying to integrate the UBER widget into it. I got logged into Uber and have given start and end destinations. When the ride request is made the app keeps on requesting.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to diagnose without seeing your code, but it looks like you have the SDK set to sandbox mode. You can change that via `[UBSDKConfiguration setSandboxEnabled:NO]` which I would suggest putting in your app delegate.

You should keep using sandbox mode while you are developing, you can update the trip status by making a PUT request to `https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/sandbox/requests/{request_id}` with a JSON body indicating what status you want to update to. For example: `{"status": "accepted"}` would put the trip into the accepted state. See the [developer docs](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sandbox) for more information